# Problema con banner de publicidad

Tags: android

resulta que estoy intentando modificar una aplicación (un emulador) para uso personal y a la hora de eliminar un banner de publicidad ha quedado un espacio en negro que toma espacio de la pantalla.

existe alguna solución para ganar ese espacio de la pantalla perdido?

aquí un imagen del problema:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aqui el main:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout android:id="@id/rootPanel" android:background="#ff000000" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <FrameLayout android:id="@id/gamePanel" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    <FrameLayout android:id="@id/adPanel" android:background="#ff000000" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Elimina el FrameLayout que contiene el anuncio, por lo que tu layout quedaría de esta forma:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout android:id="@id/rootPanel" android:background="#ff000000" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <FrameLayout android:id="@id/gamePanel" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Es importante también que en el código elimines las referecias a el FrameLayout `adPanel`

Comment: Bien me pondré en ello, estaba usando apk editor pero tal parece que tendre que usar android studio, ya que cuando elimino las lineas donde se encuentra adpanel en el codigo, al ejecutar la aplicacion esta no responde.